# Вызов нового метода анонимного класса

Tags: java, классы, класс

```
interface Lopzik{
    void petrol();
}

  public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Lopzik lopzik = new Lopzik(){
            @Override
            public void petrol() {
                System.out.println("ouch");
            }

            public String toString() {
                return "poncho";
            }
            public String kopo(){return "last";} //можно как то вызвать данный метод тут? (номер 2)
        };
        lopzik.petrol();
        // номер 2
    }
}
```

Как можно вызвать метод kopo() в методе main, если данный метод не существует в Lopzik{} а внедрен во время определения анонимного класса? Или придется использовать его только в рамках тела анонимного класса?

Внимание: Если данный вопрос вдруг оказался дубликатом, тогда просто вставьте ссылку в комментах, без негативных голосов. Если содержание ссылки дает исчерпывающий ответ, тогда я свой вопрос удалю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы сами ограничили тип переменной, когда указали конкретный тип `Lopzik lopzik = ...`

### Вариант 1

Если используется Java 10 или выше, то можно просто написать `var lopzik = ...` и тип выведется сам с нужными методами.

### Вариант 2

Если используется Java ниже 10 версии, то можно создать интерфейс с дополнительным методом `String kopo()` и наследовать его при создании анонимного класса.

### Вариант 3

В крайнем случае можно через вызвать метод так:

`(String) lopzik.getClass().getMethod("kopo").invoke(lopzik)`, но это нежелательно.

Comment: Подскажите а разве можно наследоваться при создании анонимного класса, то что в варианте 2 у вас указано? Или заранее унаследоваться при создании интерфейса Lopzik.

Comment: Можно заранее сделать наследование.

Comment: В смысле, если я правильно понял то напрямую нельзя вызвать метод. В смысле, если в интерфейсе или в классе с помощью которого создается анонимный класс - не имеет тот метод, который обьявлен в анонимном классе, то вне рамок тела этого анонимного класса не получится вызвать  этот новый метод. (Рефлексия не в счет)  я все правильно заметил?

Comment: Первый вариант позволяет вызвать метод